# Combinatorics Composition of generating fuctions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

[image]

I can follow through the whole problem except I don't understand how to get $A(x)$.

Can you run me through how to get $A(x)$?

This is my attempt,

$3$ represents the options: poisonous, slightly poisonous, not poisonous

$2$ represents the options: black or orange

$k-2$ given, # of spots

How can I think of this?

Comment: The whole problem is here http://www.math.uconn.edu/~troby/Math3250S13/Handouts/pm2solns.pdf number 1

Comment: Your attempt looks sensible, making $3\cdot 2^{k-2}$ the number of different snakes of length $k$.

Comment: why is it 2^(k-2) ?

Comment: There are $k-2$ spots. The first can be orange or black ($2$ choices), the second can be orange or black ($2$ choices), ... . Then multiply the $2$s, $k-2$ times

Comment: The way I was thinking about it is.... Let's say the snake is 5 meters long. So k = 5.
This means that the snake has 3 spots (k-2), either orange or black.

so the choices for the spots are

spot 1:orange or black
spot 2:orange or black
spot 3:orange or black

That is 6 choices, which does not equal 2^(k-2).

Comment: The order of the spots matters, so snakes of length $5$ patterned BBB, BBO, BOB, BOO, OBB, OBO, OOB, OOO are all different.

Comment: That helps, Thank you!